# Is there a way to show data on the UI without using an event handler in Angular?

Tags: angular, api

in my Angular project I'm getting data from an API using a service. Is there a way to show this data on the UI without firing an event? I saw a lot of examples which do this by clicking on a button, however I do not want to click on a button to show the data. I want this to be done whenever my page is loaded. Thanks.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

Comment: Show us your code with an example

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call API on every time of page loading you can call API in ngOnInit.